# Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$ then $a_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm thinking about the following statement:

Let $a_n$ be any real sequence, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$ then $a_n$ converges.

What comes in mind is to use Cauchy's criteria but it seems like what I'm trying to prove here is weaker, which makes me think that maybe it's not true (although it sounds true).

**EDIT:**

How to prove that $a_n$ converges after strengthening the assumption, that is, we assume that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}2^n|a_{n+1}-a_n|=L>0$$

It then becomes obvious that

$$\frac{L-\varepsilon}{2^n}<|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{L+\varepsilon}{2^n}$$

and then

$$|a_{n+1}|<|a_n|+\frac{L+\varepsilon}{2^n}  $$

so that

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\left||a_n|+\frac{L+\varepsilon}{2^n} -a_n \right|$$

However, I can't seem to make progress.

Comment: $\omega$-plicate.

Comment: $a_n:=n^{p}$ with $0<p<1$ works as counter example, too.

Comment: $0$, $1$, $1/2$, $0$, $1/4$, $2/4$, $3/4$, $1$, $7/8$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Thanks all. You proved me wrong...

Answer (score 6):

The statement is false. Take, for example,
$$
a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i
$$
for $n\ge1$. Then $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=1/(n+1)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, but the sequence $a_n$ does not converge (see [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))).

Answer (score 4):

Your statement is not true. Consider $a_n = \ln n$. Since
$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
$a_{n+1} - a_n$ converges to zero but $a_n$ diverges.

Comment: I have just realised that we have given essentially the same example since $\sum_{i=1}^ni^{-1}\sim\log n$ as $n\to\infty$ (the symbol $\sim$ means that the ratio of the two sequences tend to $1$ as $n\to\infty$). That's nice!

Comment: @V.C. I realised it when writing my answer. I chose mine just because it is typed more easily.